# Execute code in the context of another *.sh file

Tags: windows, bash

I am a newbie in these matters and feel kind of lost.

My System is Windows 7.

I have an external initialization file *init.sh*:

```
# Some code...

exec "${BASH}" --login -i
```

Now I am writing my own file *myFile.sh* which starts by calling *init.sh* and which should execute further code in the bash context of *init.sh*. I tried:

```
exec "init.sh"

# Further code here
```

Which is not working. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `source` command:

```
source "init.sh"
```

This will run the commands in the referenced script ("init.sh") as if its contents were in this script.

```
. "init.sh"
```

is a short-hand.

Answer (score 0):

`exec` instantly replaces a process with whatever was `exec`-ed. You can't run code after an `exec`, because the code that was running before the `exec` is *gone*, replaced by the new process. Normally, replacing `exec "init.sh"` with `. "init.sh"` (or `source "init.sh"`) would allow you to run the contents of `init.sh` in the current shell without replacing the shell, but because `init.sh` itself includes an `exec`, that won't work.

Given that `init.sh` is running in interactive mode, it doesn't make sense to execute further code after that in any event; a shebang (`#!init.sh`) line could be used to make `init.sh` the interpreter for the remaining code, but since it's interactive, that doesn't make sense.

It sounds an awful lot like you're trying to reinvent `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`/`.bash_login` files here; you might want to look at those instead of trying to simulate them, badly.

Comment: Short explanation what I am trying to do: init.sh is provided by the Docker System which normally starts the docker console. There you can execute the docker commands. My aim is to write a script which automatically executes multiple docker commands. I will have a look at ./bashrc / ... to see if they can help me.

Comment: @Milad: If the goal is to treat `init.sh` as a `bash` "replacement", then my shebang suggestion might make sense. Just make the first line of `myFile.sh` `#!/path/to/init.sh`, then put the "further code" below it. That should try to use `init.sh` as the interpreter for the code that follows, just like `#!/bin/bash` says the following code should be interpreted by `bash`; can't guarantee it will work thanks to the explicitly interactive thing, but it's logically appropriate here.

Comment: Well, using `#!/path/to/init.sh` the docker commands are now executed in the docker console. So, thanks so far. But I get now some docker error messages "Error occurred trying to connect..." which do not arise when executing the commands manually. Not sure why. I will check docker forum.